# Xamarin Forms (Android) - Background Service vs. Task.Run Method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created an app with Xamarin Form where a timer runs in the background. I used the Task.Run method for this and so far everything works normally when the display is not closed / turned off. When the display is closed then the timer does not run. I have informed myself that for this you should use the Background Service but I don't understand the difference between Task.Run method and Background Service. Thanks for the answer

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#:~:text=This%20guide%20discusses%20Xamarin.Android%20services%2C%20which%20are%20Android,calculations%2C%20downloading%20files%2C%20playing%20music%2C%20and%20so%20on.

Comment: If you want to run a method continuesly no matter what the app state, you need to use foreground service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Service**

The primary mechanism for background work in Android is the service. An Android service is a component that is designed to do some work without a user interface. A service might download a file, play music, or apply a filter to an image.

Background work can be broken down into two broad classifications:

**1.Long Running Task** – This is work that is ongoing until explicitly stopped. An example of a long running task is an app that streams music or that must monitor data collected from a sensor. These tasks must run even though the application has no visible user interface.

**2.Periodic Tasks** – (sometimes referred to as a job) A periodic task is one that is of relatively short in duration (several seconds) and is run on a schedule (i.e. once a day for a week or perhaps just once in the next 60 seconds). An example of this is downloading a file from the internet or generating a thumbnail for an image.

For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/ .